# How to get gold very fast?

Tags: dota-2

I played against bots and its somewhat easy to get gold while playing against bots but playing against human players its very hard to get gold.while im saving some amount of gold like 4000 most of the enemies saved like 6000 and also bought costly things like desolator and shivas guard and i hardly stand a chance against them.so anybody please tell me some tips about how to get gold faster in dota 2 and also about how to defeat enemy heroes easily.thank u

Answer (score 3):

Tips seen here at [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/DotaTips/posts/362199610496834) seem very reliable and great for gold farming. First tip from me and even @Ender about battling:

> Get better! Learn! Practice! Bring some new tricks up your sleeve or sleeves!

As of any game, virtual or not, you must learn from those who are better to improve. Of course, that info become obsolete if you don't practice the new moves. As you go up in the skill ranks, go and battle those your own size. Improve the moves that you already know and even try to change them up a little. Make some combos or something. As @Ender said:

> They are simply better.

Yep, they are. So go and practice and complete your destiny!

As for the mining tips...

> Last-Hitting

The person who gets the last hit wins all the gold. Tactics such as hit and stop might just work. You could do it the old-fashioned way: Wait then strike. Unless you have the reaction timing as Bruce Lee, don't try. Or just keep holding the "S" button util you last hit.

> Subclass 1: Look at The Mage

Mages cause significant damage to Creeps, firing at a constant rate. This will make last-hitting loads easier. Be careful when dealing with more than 1 mage or having a more-powerful weapon on the field, like a catapult.

> Subclass 2: AI Training

AI's are suppose to have perfect last-hitting skills and deny. If you can farm 5 of them successfully in single player mode, you will easily last-hit before some human player does, winning all the gold.

> Subclass 3: Animation Speed

Consider how much time it takes for your hero to strike. Sometimes, you will have to strike earlier than needed because your hero is little slow and vice versa. Melee heroes have an advantage in this section than long-range heroes.

> Neutral Creeping

Neutral creep will on average will gain you 268 gold per minute. That's as fast as Enigma can farm a gold dagger. These creeps will also give you extra protection from gankers.

> Dominate the Lane, Don't Die, Don't Waste Gold, and Use Your Skills Wisely

That's self-explanatory. Kill heroes for extra gold.

> Maximize the Map

You need to find the Creeps to kill and last hit as well. Why? Unlike Creepers in Minecraft, they don't come to you. You will have to come to them and kill them.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Can you summarise those points again, just in case, say, the post gets deleted?

Comment: Which ones? Mining or battling?

Comment: I mean the tips from Facebook.

Comment: I just finished

Answer (score 0):

Practice. A lot. Read guides. A lot. Play. A lot. Be better. A lot. There is no 
'easy way' or one, two, or three specific TIPS or TRICKS. These players are better than you, and your looking for some magical solution as to how or why. They are simply better. You need more practice.